# Folder in external drive suddenly empty! Can I recover it?

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, desktop-computer

I'm in a real pinch. The folder contains all my files from a job I just left. I was just about to create a backup when the problem occurred. I have no intention of using these files other than for personal viewing, but I doubt I can just walk back in the office and ask for them.

BACKGROUND

• It's a WD Elements 1TB 2.5 External Hard Drive

• I use it to transfer files between my PC desktop running Windows 10 and my 2017 Macbook Air running Mojave. The folder reads empty on both devices.

• I formatted it to **exFAT** about a month ago. I've been using it exclusively on PCs for about 3 years beforehand. I don't remember what format it was, but I didn't modify it then.

• I first encountered the problem on my Mac.

• Here's a screenshot of the problem.
[image]

As you can see, it says **"Zero kb, no items."** This is the only folder that's empty. Everything else is intact. I also noticed that the errant folder's "Date Modified" record is about a month off.

I'm not sure if this is relevant but if you look at the drive's info, you will see that it was **supposedly created in January 1, 1970 at 8:00AM and modified on January 1, 1980 at 12:00AM**. Neither of which is true.

THINGS I'VE TRIED (more or less in order)

PC

• Plugging the drive into my PC, the folder still showed up empty.

• Fiddling with the view settings to **show hidden files**.

• cmd: **attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:*.***

• **Scan and repair** through Properties > Tools > **Error checking** (There didn't seem to be problems)

• EaseUS trial barely found files, and not from the folder I want.

No luck.

MAC

• I put the drive back into my Mac. Waited a few minutes.

• Terminal: **sudo fsck_exfat -d**

• **[cmd] [shift] [.]**

• **First Aid** (There didn't seem to be problems)

• manually searching for my files in **.Trashes** and **Recycle Bin**. The errant folder wasn't there but I found files I deleted about a week ago, and files from a different folder deleted just yesterday before I discovered the problem.

• **[cmd] [shift] [g]** to a specific subfolder in the empty errant folder. No search result.

• Spotlight searching subfolders. No results.

• Adding then removing the folder from **Spotlight**'s Privacy settings

• **Let the drive sit in my Mac for a few hours, hoping the files would magically appear, like it has several times before in my experience of using external HDDs on Macs. Not this time.**

• iBoySoft Data Recovery was taking forever to even get past 0% so I stopped it.

Still no luck.

I suspect that recovery software won't find it because it was never really deleted?

It's probably obvious but I just want to add that I'm not a power user in any way. I'm just a noob who needs her files back. :(

Is there anything else I can try? Thank you very much!

Comment: after what you have tried, may be this is just a silly idea..but open the folder in windows and then type  *   in the search box and see if anything happens, it works for me if ever my flash drive wont display the files.

Comment: and actually the recovery software should still be able to find it even if the files were not deleted( but for that I think you have to choose full drive recovery - hope you had made partitions on that 1TB drive !! or its going to be a pretty long scan )

Comment: After a bit of scrolling, I found the folder but sadly, it's still empty. :( Thanks for the tip, though. It was worth trying! And no, I didn't partition the drive. Yikes. :D Thanks, I'll try recovering.